# batch file equivalent for this code

Tags: batch-file, scripting, redirect, echo

HI i want to implement this C code in batch file

```
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
for(int j = 0;j<i;j++)
{
  scanf("%d",&j);
  printf("%d",j);
}
```

I would run the c program using > redirection in DOS so that the printed output comes to me in a file. I want to do the same thing in my batch file where i could write something like

```
 echo %variable% >> file
```

but it doesn't work for me

```
@echo off
for %%i in (1 2 3) do (
set /p c=enter a name?
echo %%i
echo %c% >> file.txt
)
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that you want to be reading into the variable j, and printing out the address of j?  Your loop may behave oddly, and you'll always print out the same thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can't work since you need delayed variable expansion as you try to refer to a changing variable in the `if` block. You can try the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (1 2 3) do (
  set /p c=enter a name? 
  echo %%i
  echo !c! >> file.txt
)
```

as this would evaluate `c` only when the code is run, not when the line (in this case the complete `if` statement) is parsed.

A straightforward translation of your C code in batch would probably look more like the following, though:

```
@echo off
set /p i=
:loop
set /p j=
echo %j%
set /a j+=1
if %j% LSS %i% goto loop
```

You can add prompts if you like, though the C program didn't have them either :). And now you could pipe the output of the batch program as a whole or just add a `>> file` in there for good measure.

Comment: i've changed the intented solution i was expecting. I want to perform printf("%d",j); not &j. Can you tell me now.

Comment: Then this code already does what you want. I misread the old code as printf("%i", j) before, so I implemented accordingly. Hey, even my variables are named the same. As far as I can tell, my batch files does the same as the C program.